# Не корректная фоновая задача в Xamarin / Xamarin Forms, останавливается счетчик

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Пишу Xamarin Forms приложение.
Одна из функций которого запустить по требованию пользователя таймер с обратным отчетом. Т.е. пользователь выставляет время, например 5 минут - запускает - и приложение должно показывать обратный отчет: 04:45 - 04:40 - ... по окончанию уведомить пользователя о том, что время вышло. Пока тестирую на Андроиде. С локальными уведомлениями проблем не возникло, работает как надо. Но с обратным отчетом проблема. При засыпании, блокировки, переключении на другое приложение обратный отчет приостанавливается, когда возвращаюсь в приложение продолжает отчет, так может быть очень долго.
Вторая функция, это напомнить пользователю о задаче в конкретное время.
Что сделал: В нативной части реализовал Service
[image: Скрин сервиса]
[image: Скрин сервиса 2 часть]
При этом в OnStartCommand сервиса происходит запуск действия runnable и создания/ регистрация службы в качестве переднего плана, для тех устройств у которых Андроид выше Орео.

```
private void createNotificationChannel()
        {
            var NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "хххххххх.timerservice";
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "xxxxxxxService", NotificationImportance.High);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.SetOngoing(true)
                .SetContentTitle("Сервис приложения")
                .SetContentText("Запущен...")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                .SetContentIntent(BuildIntentToShowMainActivity())
                .AddAction(BuildStopServiceActionV4())
                .AddAction(BuildRestartTimerActionV4())
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .Build();            
            StartForeground(Constants.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }
```

Запуск, подписка на обновление значений отчета, остановка обратного отчета управляется из XF кода - вьюмодели -

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "ServiceStart", sett.TimeRun.ToString());    
MessagingCenter.Subscribe <object, string>(this,"TSec", (sender, arg1) =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        t.Sec = arg1;
                    });
                });
```

Заметил еще такую вещь, если подключен телефон ПК и смотрю в log, то все норм, действие обратного отчета работает.
Что может быть? или нужно как-то сохранять состояние ?
Сделал мини логирование о том как работает часть с действием runnable, если смотреть на скрин, то снизу видно, что сервис запущен, 30 сек работает норм, затем "заснул" проснулся когда приложение раскрыл из фона (4:46 на скрине). Как сделать так, чтобы таймер работал и приложение не "засыпало", таймер не замирал ?
[image: лог действия]

Answer (score 1):

Android может паузить ваши таски и грохать приложеине по своему усмотрению, как только пользователь соврачивает его или переходит к другому приложению. используйте System.Timers.Timer, например, как [здесь](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95948/use-a-timer) или [Android alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)